# Вывести транспонированную матрицу

Tags: java, массивы, циклы, матрицы

Нужно вывести транспонированную матрицу.
Вот мой код. Но он немного не так работает, как хотелось бы.
Например, при вводе значений

```
2 3

1 2 3
4 5 6
```

создаётся матрица

```
1 2 
3 4 
5 6
```

а нужно

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

вот мой код:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n, m;
    n = s.nextInt();
    m = s.nextInt();
    int[][] a = new int[m][n];
    int[][] b = new int[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b[j][i] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            a[i][j] = b[j][i];
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша программа правильно транспонирует матрицу, но не правильно ее инициализирует, если я правильно понял, то n отвечает у вас за количество строк, а m за кол-во столбцов, тогда инициализация матрицы будет выглядеть так

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
            b[i][j] = s.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

В таком случае вывод будет таким, каким вы его ожидаете

Comment: Спасибо огромное)